# expected value of threatened rooks on a chessboard?

Tags: probability

A chessboard is a 8X8 board. A rook can  threaten other pieces if they are on the same line or row. we randomnly put 8 rooks on a cheesboard. what is the expected value of threatened rooks?

I think the way  to solve this problem is by using indicators.
I'v defined 1i as a random variable that if  'rook number i' is threatened then its value is 1, otherwise 0.

then i calculate the expeceted value of this indicator and multiply this value by 8 to achive the expected value of threatened rooks.

The problem is that  the result of my calculation of the probability of the indicator is less than 0... and it doesn't make any sense...

the calculation that i did is in this link below.

what am i doing wrong in my calculation?
is there any other way to solve this problem without using indicators?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2c85.png)

Comment: Where do you get that factor of $64$ from?

Comment: I have 64 places to put the first rook without any limitation

Comment: We cannot read your linked calculation.  Please post it in the question using MathJax.

Comment: yes of course, for example if there are 3 rooks on the same line then they are all threatened

Answer (score 3):

Following your approach, let's consider a single rook at some square. Regardless of where the rook is located, there will be $15$ potential squares (out of $63$) from which other rooks can threaten it. So the probability of it not being threatened is $p = C(49, 7) / C(63, 7)$. The final answer is $8(1-p) \approx 6.76$.

Comment: i did  p=64*C(49,7)/C(64,8). why is this calculation wrong?

Comment: You're wrong because your calculation uses $64$ SQUARES but the probability concerns $8$ ROOKS.

Comment: ohh now I got it . thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did it a bit different- the probability of not being threatened is 
P=C(8,1)*C(49,7)/C(64,8)
So then 8(1-p)=6.758